# C# Data structure to sort against specific values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have an output of a method that provides two key pieces of data per result.
Eg: `20160503` and `nzdusd`.

How can I store this in a dictionary and the sort against either one?
I want to be able to sort against key or value but can't get past adding the data!
Is there another data structure better suited?

Previously I tried simply calling `Add()`

But got an `ArgumentException` with message, `An item with the same key has already been added.`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> missingDays = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Some logic
missingDays.Add(formattedDate, fxPair); // Exception here

foreach (var missingDay in missingDays)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(missingDay);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary must have unique key values. In this case the `formattedDate` variable is being assigned the same value more than once, which causes an exception the second time you try to add an entry to the dictionary with the same `formattedDate` value.

You can use a `Tuple<string, string>` inside a list (`List<Tuple<string, string>>`) to store the values, and then use the LINQ method `OrderBy()` to sort the list.

```
var missingDays = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

missingDays.Add(Tuple.Create("exampleFormattedDate", "exampleFxPair"));

foreach (var missingDay in missingDays.OrderBy(md => md.Item1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(missingDay);
}
```